# Genshin Impact Statue worshipping

Tags: halal-haram, shirk, game

Is it haram to play genshin impact, In the game itself you(the character) have to "worship" a certain statue to boost your progress, I was just wondering as it felt very off if this is permissible or not even though I myself do not associate any partners to Allah.

Comment: I mean it’s only a game so you are just playing it, as long as your intention isn’t to worship the statue in real life then it’s fine. If you still feel uncomfortable maybe stop playing this game.

Answer (score 0):

From my research I found It is forbidden to play such game. Look at the answers from Islamqa, islamweb, Shiekh Assim. Dr Zakir Naik. Etc. How can we go and play a game of worshipping idols? There are many forbidden things in video games like magic,  nudity etc idol worshipping in game is horrible. Avoid it! Genshin Impact is filled with many types of prohibited stuff. Has idols, archon, sexualized stuff, magic, churches and I think they also got crosses. Does these look halal to you?

I am trying myself to stay away from this evil game and succeed so far Alhamdulillah. I know its hard brother but remember our purpose. Also give it up for the sake of Allah and In Sha Allah He will give you something better. Don't forget, Jannah has things that we can't comprehend right now. Genshin impact doest come anywhere near to the enjoyment of afterlife!
Whatever I said i tried my best not to give false info. May Allah forgive me if I said anything wrong. AMEEN.

May Allah protect us. Ameen.